# Calculate great circle distance of all matrix elements to all matrix elements

Tags: matlab

I have the following vector of coordinates

```
LL = [lat lon]; % 5000 x 2
```

And I want to calculate the distances of all the elements to all elements using:

```
[dist, ~] = deg2km(distance[lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2]);
```

so the final matrix would be, I guess, 5000x5000. BTW the function `distance` comes in the *Mapping* toolbox. I tried a loop one-by-one, but it takes centuries to run.

**UPDATE**

```
LL = 
    -79.49583374               40.029166991
    -79.50416707               40.029166991
    -79.50416707               40.037500324

D = pdist(LL, @(x2,x1)(deg2km(distance(x1(1),x1(2),x2(1),x2(2)))))
D =
          2014.58795578131          2014.58795578131         0.168797611011563
```

while just for the first 2 coordinates:

```
D = deg2km(distance(LL(1,2),LL(1,1),LL(2,2),LL(2,1)))
D =
         0.709531880098433
```

**----**

Any help please?

Comment: Did you look at the `pdist` or `pdist2` function? With `pdist` you'll also find `squareform` helpful

Comment: yeah, but I couldn't figure it out... :/

Comment: What did you try? `squareform(pdist(LL))` or `pdist2(LL,LL)`?

Comment: I tried to use the distance function within the @distfun inside pdist, but couldn't make it work using the distance command.

Comment: Dan, the thing is that by default pdist uses the Eucidean distance, but Ineed the distance over a sphere that distance provides...

Comment: schvaba986, how you calculate the dstance in that code?

Comment: So then you need to add your `distance` function code to your question

Comment: right, it's in the question above, but I couldn enter that as an argument inside pdist.

Comment: In future, I suggest (a) mentioning if you're using any toolboxes (a.k.a where does that `distance` function come from?) and (b) if you've tried using a function (i.e. `pdist`) you must post the code of your attempt at using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realise `distance` was a Matlab function, sorry. Try this:

```
D = pdist(LL, @(x1,x2) (distance(x1(:,1),x1(:,2),x2(:,1),x2(:,2))))
```

What does `@(x1,x2) (distance(x1(:,1),x1(:,2),x2(:,1),x2(:,2)))` do?

It's an anonymous function that expects two inputs, `x1` and `x2`, and each should be *n*-by-*2*. For now let's pretend *n* equals *1*. So `pdist` will give our anonymous function every different pair of rows from `LL` as inputs `x1` and `x2`. A row from `LL` is of the form `[lat, lon]` and we are getting two such rows. We know that `distance` requires `distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)`. So if `x1` is a row of `LL` then it's `[lat1, lon1]` so `x1(1)` is actually `lat1` and `x1(2)` is actually `lon2`. Same with `x2` and `[lat2,lon2]`.

So all our anonymous function is doing is converting `distance` from a function taking 4 inputs, into a much more standard formed Matlab distance function that accepts only 2 inputs.

**EDIT:**

As you are swapping latitudes and longitudes, this might work for you:

```
D = pdist(LL, @(x1,x2) (distance(x1(:,2),x1(:,1),x2(:,2),x2(:,1))))
```

Comment: `squareform` will make it the `5000x5000` matrix you mentioned in your question btw

Comment: Actually now that I check it, I realize that there might be an issue. the command distance is defined as distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2), where (lat1,lon1) correspond to point 1, and (lat2,lon2) to point 2. Now, LL(1,:) corresonds to point 1, and LL(2,:) to point 2. By setting the arguments as specificied in the post, it's actually estimating something else. How could I fix this and make that the code uses the correct points?

Comment: Yes this is what it does. `x1` will be `LL(1,:)` so `lat1` will be `x1(1)` and `lon1` will be `x2(1)` etc... so I think that this is still correct

Comment: LL(1,1) = lat1, LL(1,2) = lon1. Then, LL(2,1)=lat2, LL(2,2)=lon2. And LL(n,1) = lat_n, LL(n,2)=lon_n

Comment: correct. that;s exactly what's happening in my code

Comment: OK, for some reason I'm getting strange values... I'll have to keep checking maybe I have a bug.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen try it with a small matrix of like 3 points only (i.e. an `LL` with only 3 rows) and then manually compute the numbers and compare. Don't forget you still need t0 call `deg2km` later

Comment: Look @Dan, I uploaded the first 3 coordinates (first column longitude and 2nd column latitude)

Comment: you are swapping your latitudes and longitudes.... so you need to do the same for my function `D = pdist(LL, @(x1,x2)(distance(x1(2),x1(1),x2(2),x2(1))))`

Comment: @OliverAmundsen Try this: `D = pdist(LL, @(x1,x2)(distance(x1(:,1),x1(:,2),x2(:,1),x2(:,2))))`

Comment: @OliverAmundsen If you have interchanged columns, try this: `D = pdist(LL, @(x1,x2)(distance(x1(:,2),x1(:,1),x2(:,2),x2(:,1))))`

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit ;) BTW, +1 for this detailed description. I didn't understand the logic before that :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
D = pdist2(LL,LL, @distfun);
```

Comment: Hi dlavila, yes, but this uses the Euclidean distance, and I need the "great circle distance" over a sphere which distance provides. See help distance

Comment: I edited my answer, you can provide your own function to `pdist2` using `@`

Comment: Right, that's what I couldn't do. how would you do that using teh command "distance"?

Comment: updapted to not confuse anyone, anyway I voted up your answer